# SWIG typemap from C char* to python string

Tags: python, c, swig, typemaps

I am trying to use a C library in Python using SWIG. This C library passes function results through arguments everywhere. Using the online SWIG manual, I have succeeded in getting an integer function result passed to Python, but I am having a hard time figuring out how to do this for a character string.

This is the essence of my code:

*myfunc.c*:

```
#include <myfunc.h>

#include <stdio.h>


int mystr(int inp, char *outstr){
   outstr="aaa";
   printf("%s\n", outstr);
   return(0);
}
```

*myfunc.h*:

```
extern int mystr(int inp, char *outstr);
```

So basically my question is what the typemap for *outstr should look like.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you really mean `outstr="aaa";`? I suspect you meant `strcpy(outstr,"aaa");`.

Comment: I guess that I did.

Comment: In particular `outstr="aaa";` wouldn't change the string that the caller passes in. The `outstr` parameter is treated as a local variable in the function, so `outstr="aaa";` just makes the local `outstr` point to an unnamed, initialized array of 4 characters `{ 'a', 'a', 'a'. '\0' }`.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the SWIG manual [9.3.4 String handling: cstring.i](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Library_nn12). This provides several typemaps for use with `char *` arguments.

Probably (assuming you are indeed using `strcpy(outstr, "aaa")` as mentioned in a comment above) you want in your SWIG interface file, before the function declaration, e.g.:

```
%include <cstring.i>
%cstring_bounded_output(char* outstr, 1024);
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I already spent quite some time looking at the manual, but as I am not a C coder, I find the manual difficult to read and the examples not easy to generalize from.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got it to work, by modifying the example in section 34.9.3 of the [SWIG 2.0 manual](http://swig.org/Doc2.0/Python.html#Python_nn53):

```
%typemap(in, numinputs=0) char *outstr (char temp) {
   $1 = &temp;
}
%typemap(argout) char *outstr {

    PyObject *o, *o2, *o3;
    o = PyString_FromString($1);
    if ((!$result) || ($result == Py_None)) {
        $result = o;
    } else {
        if (!PyTuple_Check($result)) {
            PyObject *o2 = $result;
            $result = PyTuple_New(1);
            PyTuple_SetItem($result,0,o2);
        }
        o3 = PyTuple_New(1);
        PyTuple_SetItem(o3,0,o);
        o2 = $result;
        $result = PySequence_Concat(o2,o3);
        Py_DECREF(o2);
        Py_DECREF(o3);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `temp` is just a single `char`, so this code will at some point segfault if your `outstr` is ever longer than 1 `char`. Otherwise, your code is essentially a simplified version of `%cstring_bounded_output`.